# Change background color of C++ console app

Tags: c++, console-application, background-color

How do I go about changing the foreground color of a console app if I wanted to use colors other than green, red, blue?  Below is a portion of my code:

```
case GreenFlag:
    indicator = GreenFlag;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), BACKGROUND_GREEN);
    cout << "Green message" << endl;
    break;
case OrangeFlag:
    indicator = OrangeFlag;
    // SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), BACKGROUND_ORANGE);
    cout << "Orange message" << endl;
    break;
case RedFlag:
    indicator = RedFlag;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), BACKGROUND_RED);
    cout << "Red message" << endl;
    break;
case WhiteFlag:
    indicator = WhiteFlag;
    // SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), BACKGROUND_WHITE);
    cout << "White message" << endl;
    break;
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You asked:**

> how to use colors other than green, red, blue?

You may combine the flags to create new colors:

> An application can combine the foreground and background constants to
>   achieve different colors. For example, the following combination
>   results in bright cyan text on a blue background.
>
> FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY |
>   BACKGROUND_BLUE
>
> If no background constant is specified, the background is black, and
>   if no foreground constant is specified, the text is black. For
>   example, the following combination produces black text on a white
>   background.
>
> BACKGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_RED

Beyond that, you may set colors individually on each char and/or modify the screen buffer attributes:

> Each screen buffer character cell stores the color attributes for the
>   colors used in drawing the foreground (text) and background of that
>   cell. An application can set the color data for each character cell
>   individually, storing the data in the Attributes member of the
>   CHAR_INFO structure for each cell. The current text attributes of each
>   screen buffer are used for characters subsequently written or echoed
>   by the high-level functions.
>
> An application can use GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo to determine the
>   current text attributes of a screen buffer and the
>   SetConsoleTextAttribute function to set the character attributes.
>   Changing a screen buffer's attributes does not affect the display of
>   characters previously written. These text attributes do not affect
>   characters written by the low-level console I/O functions (such as the
>   WriteConsoleOutput or WriteConsoleOutputCharacter function), which
>   either explicitly specify the attributes for each cell that is written
>   or leave the attributes unchanged.

**For documentation and example see:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/using-the-high-level-input-and-output-functions

Comment: Thanks for the answer @durune.
I'll give it a go & see if I can come up with the colors I need!
Cheers

Comment: @TimothyKruger no worries, let me know if you encounter any issues.

Comment: Cheers will do ;-).